# Adding a CHM help file in VSIX to distributed developer guide

Tags: vsix, vsixmanifest

I am writing VSIX to distribute a multi-project template with wizard for VS 2013, which allow user to write extensions for our application. I have problem in providing a user guide document, which is a chm file, along with template. VSIX manifest allow me to provide a "Getting Started Guide", however file support by these feature does not includes "CHM" file.

We use RoboHelp to create CHM, there is an option to create html files too. however the html files created are multiple files distributed into multiple folders (there is a index page, which has the link to all other html files). I am not sure how to package these files into VSIX.

I have few questions here;

1. Is it possible for us to run any script or batch file as part of
   vsix installation?
2. Is it possible to create a Windiows Start manu folder to show a link to chm file?
3. If I point "Getting Started Guide" to any inner directory html file.
   "Getting Started" link is not available in "Extensions and Updates",
   is there any work around?
4. Am I doing all wrong? is there better way to provide a template &
   help?

If i decide to deploy html help; I am thinking of deploying zipped copy of getting started help, which have many folder and files, then extract during the vsix  installation. otherwise i need to mark each of those 100+ file as "Include in VSIX"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Made chm file as part of vsix and marked it as "Include in VSIX" as
   suggested by @Carlos Quintero
2. Create a new Visual Studio Package project (using Templates -> Visual C# -> Extensibility -> Visual Studio Package) for adding a new menu item for our sdk help under VS IDE "Help" menu.Visual Studio Package wizard will be shown

   Page 1) Welcome page

   Page 2) Select a Programming Language: allow us to choose a programing language & way to sign the assembly

   Page 3) Basic VSPackage Information: like company name, VSPackage name, icon, etc.

   Page 4) Select VSPackage Options: Select Menu Command checkbox, This menu item will be added in VS IDE -> Tools

   Page5) Command Options: Provided information for the menu, name & id.
   After providing this information "Finish" the wizard using button
   provided.
3. Open the ".vsct" file in the newly created project and look for "IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS" and change it to "IDM_VS_MENU_HELP" move the menu item to VS IDE -> Help
4. MenuItemCallback method in the main class of the project to open chm file.

   ```
   private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e){
   string codeBase = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
   UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
   string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
   string helpFilePath = string.Format("file://{0}\\myHelp.chm", System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path))
   System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(null, helpFilePath);    }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the .chm (or any other file type) to the package project, select the file in the Solution Explorer, show the Properties window for the file (not for the project, and set the "Include in VSIX" property to true.

Comment: how can I provide a link to that chm file. One way I know is create a html file show that in "Getting started..". In that html file provide an option to download the "CHM" file. Is that the only way?

Comment: AFAIK, VSIX doesn't allow custom actions, MSI would be required. In a package the easiest way would be a "Help" menu entry or button inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the "Help" menu entry suggestion, that prompt me to look at Templates -> Visual C# -> Extensibility -> Visual Studio Package.

Answer (score 0):

1: you can run any code on launch of your extension.
2: you can add any commands to the Tools menu

Comment: It is Project template, i am thinking of deploying zipped copy of getting started help, which have many folder and files, then extract during the vsix  installation. otherwise i need to mark each of those 100+ files "Include in VSIX"